# Filter instance based on multiple tags in Lambda Python code

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I want to check if a certain instance has list of tags on it. Tags I am interested in are Environment, Env, and environment. And their values are Production, Prod, and production. I am using a lambda function for checking it and I have this so far:

```
response = ec2.describe_tags(
Filters=[
    {
        'Name': 'tag:Environment|Env|environment',
        'Values': [
            'Production|production|Prod',
        ]
    },
    {
        'Name': 'resource-id',
        'Values': [
            instance_id,
        ],
    }
])
print(response)
```

But this doesn't catch proper tags on instance. I believe the problem is me trying to catch multiple tags in "Key1|Key2|Key3" format. Can anyone please advise correct way of filtering through multiple tags? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to work base on **EC2 event** using lambda, then you better to get instance base on **Instance ID** that is available in EC2 event, get the tags and perform the further operation.

```
ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')
specificinstance = ec2.describe_instances(Filters=[
{
    'Name': 'instance-id',
    'Vdataalues': [
        event["detail"]["EC2InstanceId"]
        ],
}])
TAGS=specificinstance["Reservations"][0]["Instances"][0]["Tags"]
pprint(TAGS)
```

Or I did not find a way to filter instance base on different `tag-key` but here is the example that might help, which filter base on a different value.

```
import boto3  
client = boto3.client('ec2') 
filters = [{  
    'Name': "tag:environment",
    'Values': ['prod','production','Production']
    }]
response = client.describe_instances(Filters=filters)
print response
```

This will filter if it container `environment` like `prod,production,Production`

To filter with instance IP, or reservation ID

```
import boto3  
client = boto3.client('ec2') 
filters = [{  
    'Name': "tag:environment",
    'Values': ['prod,production,Production']
    },
    {
    'Name': 'instance-id',
    'Values': [
        'i-123456789',
        ],
}]
response = client.describe_instances(Filters=filters)
print response
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to do in **three separate calls**. At least this is what I can conclude from my exterminates on several instances.

An example that I used is below:

```
import boto3

from pprint import pprint

ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')

tag_values = ['production', 'Prod', 'Production']
tag_names = ['Env', 'Environment', 'environment']

results = []

for tag_name in tag_names:

    r=ec2.describe_tags(
            Filters=[{
                    'Name':'tag:' + tag_name,
                    'Values': tag_values
          }])

    pprint(r)

    results.append(r)


pprint(results)
```